# Convert VB Loop to Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this to work in Javascript.  It works fine in Visual Basic.  How do I properly call out the correct rows and columns for the loop to work?

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
i = 2
j = 6
k = 1

Do While k < 200
    If Cells(i, j) <= Sheets("Outlines").Cells(1, 8) Then
        Cells(i, j - 3) = Cells(i, j)
        Cells(i, j - 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, j - 5), Sheets("View").Range("A2:P48"), 4, False)
        Cells(i, j - 1) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, j - 5), Sheets("View").Range("A2:P48"), 5, False)
    End If
    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1
Loop
```

Comment: there is no Sheets or Cells in javascript / html , and whtt is `Application.VLookup()`?

Comment: If you want to manipulate an Excel spreadsheet from JavaScript, then you'll need to find a JavaScript library e.g. exceljs.

Answer (score 0):

1 to one conversion assuming the VBCalls have lowerCase JS equivalents

```js
let i = 2, j = 6, k = 1;

while (k < 200) {
  if (cells(i, j) <= sheets("Outlines").cells(1, 8)) {
    cells(i, j - 3) = cells(i, j)
    cells(i, j - 2) = application.VLookup(cells(i, j - 5), sheets("View").range("A2:P48"), 4, false)
    cells(i, j - 1) = application.VLookup(Cells(i, j - 5), sheets("View").range("A2:P48"), 5, false)
  }
  i++;
  k++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The debug produces no errors, but when I run it in Google Sheets, I get a cell not defined error.  (FYI ... I'm a novice at this.)